# How can I change the background color of the hint text of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I am programming a view of TextInputLayout

My style.xml is :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My color overrides in color.xml are:

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#c2261a</color>
```

My TextInput Layout is:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/weightInput"
        style="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_weight"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:helperTextEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And the final result is

[image: final result]

As we can see the background color of the hint text is transparent. How can I find that view.

I tried that style without success:

My style.xml is :

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HintText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 6):

Updating to material components 1.4.0-alpha01 resolves this issue.
This is the commit responsible: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/6015a4e901dc55a02f86e12703820d520684f95e

Answer (score -4):

**This is to change the line color of edit text.**

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
```

sample code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    tools:text="Full name" />
```